# Python http.server not responding back to the client

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax

I am creating a chatting project using python module http.server as server and on the client side i am using jquery ajax to send and recieve messages... But matter is that the client is able to send messages to the server and server is recieving messages(checked with print statement) but when its time to return back the messages again to all clients, i think the server is not responding the messages to clients. I am not getting what's problem with the code. It would be great help if you find the bug...

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer,ThreadingHTTPServer
import json

class handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")
        self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
        self.end_headers()

        #just trying
        message = {"room4":1,"room5":1,"room6":1}
        self.wfile.write(json.dumps(message).encode())
    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        body = self.rfile.read(content_length)
        if content_length:
            data=json.loads(body.decode())
            
            keys=list(data.keys())
            if keys[0]=="message":
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")
                self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
                self.send_header('Cache-Control', 'no-store')
                self.end_headers()
                message = {"welcome_msg":"success"}
                print("Data:",data)
                self.wfile.write(json.dumps(message).encode())
            else:
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")
                self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
                self.send_header('Cache-Control', 'no-store')
                self.end_headers()
serv=HTTPServer(("localhost",9889),handler)
serv.serve_forever()
```

javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    load();
    var entereddata;
    $("#submitbtn").click(function(){
        var d=new Date()
        var t=d.getTime()
        var time = d.toLocaleTimeString();
        entereddata=$("#msgarea").val()
        $("#chat").append("<div id='msg' style='background-color:#dcf8c6;padding:5px 10px; border-radius:5px;margin-bottom:8px;width:fit-content' class='container_new' style='margin-left:200px;'>"+"You: "+entereddata+"<p class='time-right'>&emsp;"+time+"</p>"+"</div>")
        //var element = document.getElementById("msgarea");
        //window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight-element.clientHeight);
        $.post("http://localhost:9889/",JSON.stringify({
            "message":entereddata,
            "port":location.port,
            })
        )
    })

    function load(){
        //console.log("hhh")
        $.post("http://localhost:9889/",JSON.stringify({
            "port":location.port,
            }),function(data,status){
                console.log("ds")
                console.log(data)
                
            }
        )
    }
    setInterval(load,1000)
    
})
```

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
          margin: 0;
          overflow:hidden;
        }
        #chat{
          height:88vh;
          overflow:hidden;
          padding: 10px;;
        }
        .container_new {
          border: 2px solid #dedede;
          background-color: #f1f1f1;
          border-radius: 5px;
          padding: 10px;
          margin: 10px 0;
        }
        
        .darker {
          border-color: #ccc;
          background-color: #ddd;
        }
        
        .container::after {
          content: "";
          clear: both;
          display: table;
        }
        
        .container img {
          float: left;
          max-width: 60px;
          width: 100%;
          margin-right: 20px;
          border-radius: 50%;
        }
        
        .container img.right {
          float: right;
          margin-left: 20px;
          margin-right:0;
        }
        
        .time-right {
          float: right;
          color: #aaa;
        }
        
        .time-left {
          float: left;
          color: #999;
        }
        #form{
          display: flex;
        }
        input{
          font-size:1.2rem;
          padding:10px;
          margin:10px 5px;
          appearance:none;
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
          border-radius: 5px;
        }
        #msgarea{
          flex:2
        }
        #msg{
          background-color: #dcf8c6;
          padding:5px 10px;
          border-radius: 5px;
          margin-bottom: 8px;
        }
        </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body id="bod">
    <h2 id="head2"></h2>
    <div class="container-fluid " id="chat"> 
    </div>
    <div id="form">
        <input autofocus  placeholder="Enter Message..." name="" id="msgarea" ></input>
        <input type="button" id="submitbtn" value="Send">
    </div>  
    
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks